# How to make video wall with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video-processing

I need to generate video file with iphone SDK that looks like a wall of few smaller videos. Did somebody could help me with advice how to implement this? I am currently thinking of images with frames, that placed in UIView in needed order and then assemble them in one final video, but I can't find how to do it.

Here's how it should look:

| video1 | video2 |
| -------- | --------- |
| video3 | video4 |
 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if somebody interesting it could be done with AVVideoComposition. You add AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction to your VideoComposition and then use usual CGAffineTransform on that layer. But the maximum amount of videos on the screen is 4, so if you need more, then just do it in few steps.

Comment: I nee more information about this, can you please describe me more or share some code for this?